# Translating Stata variable coding into R code

Tags: r, encoding, stata

I have the following variable coding in a Stata `do` file that I tried to convert into R:

**Stata**

```
gen A=q1 if q1<4
gen B=q2 if q2<4
gen C=q3 if q3<4
...
```

**R**

```
# Example data
data = read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/BHUJpwqQ")

data$A <- subset(data,q1<4)
...
```

Returns:

> data$A <- data$q1[data$q1 < 4]
>   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "A", value = list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L,  : 
>     replacement has 106 rows, data has 144

**Question:**

How can I correctly transfer the Stata command into R?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] so we can replicate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try `within(data, df$A <- ifelse(q1<9, q1, ifelse(q1>=9, NA, NA)))`

Comment: I can't believe the R equivalent to a simple Stata command is that long?

Comment: No, returns `Error in df$A <- ifelse(q1 < 9, q1, ifelse(q1 >= 9, NA, NA)) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. But also can't beliebe there is no simpler way?

Comment: Well we need to see the data. Your `pastebin` link does not work.

Comment: I just checked it, https://pastebin.com/raw/BHUJpwqQ should work?

Comment: Sorry it should be `within(data, data$A <- ifelse(q1<4, q1, ifelse(q1>=4, NA, NA)))` . Let me know if this works.

Comment: Still doesn't work. But again, I can't imagine that the R code solution is that long anyways? Anyone an idea?

Comment: It works fine on my computer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
data$A <- ifelse(data$q1 < 4, data$q1, NA)
```

In action:

```
> data <- data.frame(q1 = sample(2:6))
> data
  q1
1  5
2  2
3  3
4  6
5  4
> data$A <- ifelse(data$q1 < 4, data$q1, NA)
> data
  q1  A
1  5 NA
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  6 NA
5  4 NA
```

Comment: That did the job. Do I correctly understand that it essentially replaces values <4 with NA, or >4?

Comment: `A` is created and becomes equal to `q1` when `q1 < 4` else `NA`.